# Convert a ffmpeg video to an appropriate dimension

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am writing a video conversion script using ffmpeg, it has been completed to full. Ideally, my video conversion script should output the video to many formats (like YouTube):

- 140p: 256   x 144
- 240p: 426   x 240
- 360p: 640   x 360
- 480p : 854  x 480
- 720p : 1280 x 720
- 1080p : 1920x 1080

The problem I am facing is that if a user uploads a 480p (854 x 480) video or close to 480p (854 x 480) the script will convert to all formats (1080p and 720p) which would seem like a waste of bandwidth and disk space in this case.

The problem isn't as easy as it seems. If a user uploads a 500 x 300 video I don't want it to get converted to a 240p, there has to be some estimations.

Who can help me or has some experience with such kind of problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to measure the size of the video first with something like "mplayer -identify " and only convert to the standard sizes that are (say) 5% smaller than the size of the source plus the next larger standard size.

Okay, more detail

```
mplayer -quiet  -identify -vo null -ao null -endpos 0.1 The\ Cat\ Came\ Back.mpg 2>/dev/null  | grep ID_VIDEO
```

Gives

```
ID_VIDEO_ID=0
ID_VIDEO_FORMAT=0x10000001
ID_VIDEO_BITRATE=1150000
ID_VIDEO_WIDTH=352
ID_VIDEO_HEIGHT=240
ID_VIDEO_FPS=29.970
ID_VIDEO_ASPECT=0.0000
ID_VIDEO_CODEC=ffmpeg1
ID_VIDEO_ASPECT=1.3394
```

Lets say you multiply the height by the width and reduce that by 5%

```
352*240*0.95 = 80256
```

Then go through your list of standard sizes in order and if this one is less than the W*H of the standard size you encode it. If it's larger then you still encode it but once you're done you don't encode any more.

Note you can look at the "ID_VIDEO_ASPECT" and choose different 'standard sizes' based on that value if you like.